# Parse (extract) content from a html page using .net

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, html-parsing

I need to parse/extract information from an html page.
Basically what I'm doing is loading the page as a string using System.Net.WebClient and using HTML Agility Pack to get content inside html tags (forms, labels, imputs and so on).

However, some content is inside a javascript script tag, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var itemCol = new Array();

itemCol[0] = {
    pid: "01010101",
    Desc: "Some desc",
    avail: "Available",
    price: "$10.00"
};

itemCol[1] = {
    pid: "01010101",
    Desc: "Some desc",
    avail: "Available",
    price: "$10.00"
};

//]]>
</script>
```

So, how could I parse it to a collection in .NET? Can HTML Agility Pack help with that?
I really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HAP will not parse out the javascript for you - the best it will do is parse out the contents of the element.

[javascript.net](https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net) may fit the bill.

Comment: For some reason I was unable to install javascript.net (got some errors) but anyways, i was able to do the same with Jint. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

what part of the content inside the script tag do you want? What kind of collection are you expecting. You can always select script tags using below

```
  HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
  document.Load(downloadedHtml);
  XPathNavigator n = document.CreateNavigator();
  XPathNodeIterator scriptTags = n.Select("//script");

  foreach (XPathNavigator nav in scriptTags)
  {
    string innerXml = nav.InnerXml;

    // Parse inner xml using regex
  }
```

Comment: using javascript.net 
      
     using (JavascriptContext context = new JavascriptContext())
      {
        context.SetParameter("data", new MyObject());
      
         StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (XPathNavigator nav in scriptTags)
        {
           s.Append(nav.InnerXml);
        }

      s.Append(";data.item = itemCol;");
      context.Run(s.ToString());

      MyObject o = context.GetParameter("data") as MyObject;


Then just have a datastructure like 
class MyObject
  {
    public object item { get; set; }
  }

Answer (score 1):

using the javascript.net library you can get a collection

```
 using (JavascriptContext context = new JavascriptContext())
  {
    context.SetParameter("data", new MyObject());

     StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (XPathNavigator nav in scriptTags)
    {
       s.Append(nav.InnerXml);
    }

  s.Append(";data.item = itemCol;");
  context.Run(s.ToString());

  MyObject o = context.GetParameter("data") as MyObject;
```

Then just have a datastructure like

```
   class MyObject
   {
     public object item { get; set; }
   }
```